# Why is "ExecStart=" defined twice in customexec.config (Varnish Cache)?

Tags: varnish

Why is `ExecStart=` defined twice and why is the first one empty? Is it because Varnish will start two processes, one parent and one child? If so, where can I read about it?
I can't seem to find any information about this.

In Varnish's own documentation, again and again across versions, this is the instruction:

[image: Varnish config Debian / Ubuntu instructions]

Source: https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/tutorial/putting_varnish_on_port_80.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStart= :

> Unless Type= is oneshot, exactly one command must be given. When Type=oneshot is used, zero or more commands may be specified. Commands may be specified by providing multiple command lines in the same directive, or alternatively, this directive may be specified more than once with the same effect. If the empty string is assigned to this option, the list of commands to start is reset, prior assignments of this option will have no effect. If no ExecStart= is specified, then the service must have RemainAfterExit=yes and at least one ExecStop= line set. (Services lacking both ExecStart= and ExecStop= are not valid.)

Long story short:

- All occurences of `ExecStart` are executed, unless `Type=oneshot`
- By setting `ExecStart=`, we're making sure that previous values are removed
- By setting `ExecStart` again with an actual value, only this command will be executed